# How can I get the text in a button exactly in the centre?

Tags: android, button

I am unable to get the '×' (multiplication symbol) in the shown button exactly in the centre. It seems a bit off. How can I bring it back in centre?
Here is the xml code for it.

[image]

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_multiply"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:elevation="24dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="@string/button_multiply"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp" />
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an odd problem that catches everyone at first - you need text alignment AND gravity which must match

```
<Button
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    ... />
```

Comment: Tried but still not working. Any other ideas. Uploaded the button image so that it can give you clearer idea.

Comment: That definitely works, so can you check the view itself is the setup correctly - either it needs to have width=match_parent (which it doesn't) or it needs to be centered within it's parent too (you'll need to post the rest of your layout if you cant resolve it)